# What is meaning of this piece of code in typescript? public testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Undecided";

Tags: angular, typescript

```
public testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Undecided";
```

1. What is meaning of this piece of code in typescript?
2. What is type of variable testOptions?
3. Is testOptions an array, string or some thing else?
4. What does "No" = "Undecided" mean?
5. What does pipe symbol "|" mean?

Comment: Does it compile and run without errors?

Comment: It means you have a public property in your class that can have one of following values: `"Undecided" | "Yes" | "No"` and its default value is `"Undecided"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes sir, it compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: oh nice, I learned something today :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Types that are separated with a pipe symbol `|` are called union-types and can be read as an `OR` operation. The `=` sign in this case denotes an assignment. Meaning property `testOptions` has the default value `"Undecided"`

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
// Foo is of type string, but not just any string, only the literal values
// "Undecided", "Yes", or "No". Any other string won't match the type.
type Foo = "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No";

// Will error because "bar" is not one of "Undecided", "Yes", or "No"
const a: Foo = "bar";

// Will work
const b: Foo = "Undecided";
```

To learn more about the advanced types in TypeScript, I'd highly recommend the [docs on advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 3):

In typescript, type of variable is define as `variableName: type`.

Type can be anything.

- Primitive values: string, number
- Complex values: MyClass1, IInterface1

There is also a union operator (`|`) which is used to merge more than 1 type.

So if you have a variable that can have either number or string, it will be defined as `variable: number | string`.

Now what if you want to have a variable that can only have specific values in a specific type?

> public testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Undecided";

So now your `testOptions` can have `"Undecided" | "Yes" | "No"` and you can setting its default as `"Undecided"`

Answer (score 1):

```
public testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Undecided";
```

1. You have defined a variable which is string.
2. string but one of `"Undecided" | "Yes" | "No"`

If you change the value like

```
public testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "decided";
```

it'll throw error, because it's string but it should  be out of `"Undecided" | "Yes" | "No"`

This code has created a new type just like string, objject, number; this code created a user defined type which is

```
type UndecideYesNoType = "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like a shorthanded `enum`...

The following will compile:

```
testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Undecided";
testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "Yes";
testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "No";
testOptions: "a" | "b" | "c" = "a";
```

This will not compile:

```
testOptions: "Undecided" | "Yes" | "No" = "xxx";
testOptions: "a" | "b" | "c" = "xxx";
```

Because "xxx" does not exist in that advanced type declaration.

As opposed to an enum:

```
enum MyEnum{
    Undecided= 1,
    Yes,
    No
}
testOptions:MyEnum = MyEnum.Yes; <-- so much easier to understand
```